# A-Frame WASD controls substitute on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

I have an A-Frame multiplayer project, which relies on each user moving around the map, and it works well in desktop browsers. The stumbling block is the lack of motion controls in mobile, like the WASD-controls for the camera.

What workaround would you suggest? Perhaps, adding on-screen buttons and triggering keypress events with jQuery?

Or is there a more straightforward method of adding a function that would change the camera position for each on-screen button press? In this case, is there a way to find the exact functions attributed to the W, A, S, D keys?

Among several things I've tried was:

```
$(".up-button").click(function(){
  window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{keyCode: 38}));
```

And another one:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 38;
$(window).trigger(e);
```

Neither is producing any change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{keyCode: 38} )  );
```

to simulate pressing the up arrow key?

You could simulate pressing wasd or up down left right.
The rotation might be a little more tricky though,
you would have to simulate the onMouseDown and onMouseMove events.

Comment: There are also "onTouch" events made for mobile devices. I'm about to go to work, but will look for the .js repository I saw the other day that took advantage of them. You've waited 18 days with no other answers.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried simulating keypress events with divs but had no luck before. I'll try your line and let you know.

Comment: I got a cheap Mocute $5 bluetooth remote on ebay. I'm trying to use that to simulate clicks. But still befuddled.

Comment: That's an option, too! I really want to resolve this with no additional hardware, so anyone with a smartphone can connect and move around right away. I found this repo, which includes a script for touch-controls, but still trying to figure out how to implement it: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls

Comment: Yeah, I like the touch controls for a testing option, but My website is used sitting at a desk on a PC on a phone or tablet while riding (hopefully not driving!) or plugging your phone into a head mounted display for the full 3D VR experience. That's the reason I went with the remote, had to touch screen in the last situation. More info about your multiplayer project would be helpful, (as well as interesting).

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean. Most people wouldn't even have a controller to properly move the character in your project/game. I've seen in a demo in A-Frame that is pretty clever in my opinion. Basically if the user is looking down on floor, then the camera moves forward. This is good as it requires no outside input whatsoever so it works on everything.

As how to implement it, this may be a solution:

```
//First calculate the verticle angle of the camera

     var verticalAngle = getVerticalAngle(camera.getWorldDirection());
        console.log('vertical angle:' + verticalAngle);
        function getVerticalAngle(cameraVector) {
            return vRadiansToDegrees(Math.atan(cameraVector.y));
        }

        function vRadiansToDegrees(radians) {
            return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
        }
```

And then move the camera forward if the user is looking down on the floor

```
if (verticalAngle < -43) {
      //move camera
    }
```

Comment: This is quite ingenious! I'll try it when I have a moment and will let you know how it goes + post a link. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can call the exact function that moves the camera smoothly, in the direction that the camera is pointing in, just like the W key would?

Comment: What function are you calling when you press the W key? You should use the same function that you are using with the key presses. Personally I use this: https://github.com/brianpeiris/three-firstperson-vr-controls/blob/master/README.md which saves me a lot of time.

Comment: That's a great reference. The thing with A-Frame is — stock WASD movement comes preinstalled and I am not quite sure where to find it.

Comment: Oh I see, I have never used A-Frame before so I can't help with that.